# Run fleet with on demand instance across AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

0
Hello,
I wanted to start EC2 fleet with on-demand instances only, and I wanted them to be distributed across availability zones. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to do that, and all the instances are always started in a single AZ.
That is not a problem with spot instances, as they spawn in all the AZ.
I was trying to try different allocation strategies and priorities, but nothing helped.
I was trying to do so in AWS-CDK, using both `CfnEC2Fleet` [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnEC2Fleet.html) as well as `CfnSpotFleet` [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnSpotFleet.html). Bellow is my code.
Is there way how to achieve that, or do I need to use something else? I know I can achieve the same results using auto-scaling groups, I just wonder whether I can use fleet to get this functionality.
Thank you.

```
const spotFleet = new CfnSpotFleet(stack, 'EC2-Fleet', {
    spotFleetRequestConfigData: {
        allocationStrategy: 'lowestPrice',
        targetCapacity: 8,
        iamFleetRole: fleetRole.roleArn,
        spotMaintenanceStrategies: {
            capacityRebalance: {
                replacementStrategy: 'launch-before-terminate',
                terminationDelay: 120,
            }
        },
        onDemandTargetCapacity: 4,
        instancePoolsToUseCount: stack.availabilityZones.length,
        launchTemplateConfigs: [{
            launchTemplateSpecification: {
                launchTemplateId: launchTemplate.launchTemplateId,
                version: launchTemplate.latestVersionNumber,
            },
            overrides: privateSubnets.map(subnet => ({
                availabilityZone: subnet.subnetAvailabilityZone,
                subnetId: subnet.subnetId,
            })),
        }],
    }
});

const ec2Fleet = new CfnEC2Fleet(stack, 'EC2-EcFleet', {
    targetCapacitySpecification: {
        totalTargetCapacity: 6,
        onDemandTargetCapacity: 6,
        defaultTargetCapacityType: 'on-demand',
    },
    replaceUnhealthyInstances: true,
    onDemandOptions: {
        allocationStrategy: 'prioritized',
    },
    launchTemplateConfigs: [{
        launchTemplateSpecification: {
            launchTemplateId: launchTemplate.launchTemplateId,
            version: launchTemplate.latestVersionNumber,
        },
        overrides: privateSubnets.map(subnet => ({
            availabilityZone: subnet.subnetAvailabilityZone,
            subnetId: subnet.subnetId,
        })),
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating placement groups as well that spans multi AZ and have the launch template using this placement group. I don't really know if that is a solution that you are after.
But I would say ASG is what should be used if you don't have a need for certain kind of placement you get out of placement groups.
I am kinda sure this cant be done in any other way.